# Help with proving this three part theorem left to reader to prove by Halmos

Tags: linear-algebra

> Every set of $n+1$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ is linearly dependent. A set of $n$ vectors in $V$ is a basis if and only if it is linearly independent, or, alternatively, if and only if every vector in $V$ is a linear combination of elements of the set. (Paul R. Halmos, *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces*, 2e, section 8, theorem 2, page 14)

Comment: In this kind of questions I think it is specially important that you tell what  you already know, what can you assume (or we to assume you know), what have you achieved so far, etc., otherwise it is very difficult to guess what can help you.

Comment: One day you may need to write a paper with proper references: in preparation for that day, you should bear in mind the fact that Halmos wrote more than one book.

Comment: Explicitly defining a basis will help you.

Comment: People here are happy to help, so you need to indicate what part you are having difficult with.

Comment: Hi all. I sorry for the delay. I am just really struggling with the first part. Showing that n+1 vectors are linearly dependent. Is it simply because the basis would only have n vectors? I feel like I need to take it a little farther though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refering to Paul R. Halmos, *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces*, 2e:

Theorem 2 in section 8, page 14:

**First part**

> Every set of $n + 1$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space is
>   linearly dependent.

Theorem 1 in the same section states:

> The number of elements in any basis of a finite-dimensional vector
>   space $\mathcal{V}$ is the same as in any other basis.

If there is a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors, taken from the set of $n +1$ linearly dependent vectors, they form a basis. This is a consequence of the theorem in section 7:

> If $\mathcal{V}$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and 
>   $\{y_1, ..., y_m\}$ is any set of linearly independent vectors in $\mathcal{V}$,
>   then, unless the $y$'s already form a basis, we can find vectors
>   $y_{m+1}, ..., y_{m+p}$ so that the totality of the $y$'s, that is,
>   $\{y_1, ..., y_m, y_{m+1}, ..., y_{m+p}\}$, is a basis. In other
>   words, every linearly independent set can be extended to a basis.

Since every linearly independent set can be extended to a basis, so can the set of $n$ linearly independent vectors chosen from the set of $n + 1$ vectors. But since every basis has $n$ elements, it already is one.

Now that it is shown that every set of $n$ linearly independent vectors is a basis, every vector in the vector space can be expressed as a linear combination of the $n$ linearly independent vectors chosen from the set of $n + 1$ vectors. Hence, if you add an arbitrary vector to the set of $n$ linearly independent vectors, it will be a linear combination of the other ones. But then, according to the theorem in section 6, the set is linearly dependent:

> The set of non-zero vectors $x_1, ..., x_n$ is linearly dependent if
>   and only if some $x_k$, $2 \le k \le n$, is a linear combination of
>   the preceding ones.

If, on the other hand, you cannot find $n$ linearly independent vectors from the given set of $n + 1$ vectors, then the whole set is linearly dependent. Since every set containing a linearly dependent subset is itself linearly dependent.

---

**Second part**

> A set of $n$ vectors in $\mathcal{V}$ is a basis if and only if it is
>   linearly independent.

"$\Rightarrow$": From the definition of a basis (section 7, page 10) the constituting vectors have to be linearly independent:

> A (linear) *basis* (or a *coordinate system*) in a vector space
>   $\mathcal{V}$ is a set $\mathcal{X}$ of linearly independent vectors
>   such that every vector in $\mathcal{V}$ is a linear combination of
>   elements of $\mathcal{X}$.

"$\Leftarrow$": Using the same argument as in the first part, if there is a set of linearly independent vectors with the same number of elements than a basis of the vector space, then it is a basis, since every set of linearly independent vectors can be extended to a basis.

---

**Third part**

> A set of $n$ vectors in $\mathcal{V}$ is a basis if and only if every
>   vector in $\mathcal{V}$ is a linear combination of elements of the
>   set.

"$\Rightarrow$": From the definition of a basis (see above) every vector of the vector space is a linear combination of the basis' elements.

"$\Leftarrow$": Assume there is a set of $n$ vectors such that every vector in the vector space is a linear combination of those. Assume also that these vectors do not form a basis. If they don't, they are linearly dependent (from the definition of a basis). As a consequence, the maximum number of linearly independent vectors in this set is $n-1$. From the theorem in section 7 (see above), every linearly independent set can be extended to a basis. But regardless which vector is added to the set, it is a linear combination of the remaining elements in the set. Hence, the set is linearly dependent and there is a linearly independent set which cannot be extended to a basis. A contradiction. To make the implication true, we might negate the premise:

For all sets of vectors such that every vector in the vector space is a linear combination of those we have that they form a basis.